# Overflow occurs with multiplication

Tags: java, multiplication, integer-overflow

```
long m = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

The above code creates overflow and doesn't print the correct result.

```
long m2 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
long m3 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000L;
```

The above 2 lines print the correct result.

My questions are-

1. Does it matter to the compiler which I use, `m2` or `m3`?
2. How does java starts multiplying? Left to right or right to left? Does 24*60 gets computed first or 1000*1000?

Comment: oops- 
long m2 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000*1000*1000;
long m3 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000*1000* 1000L;

m2 and m3 don't give same result when mutiplied more say by a factor of 1000*1000. So it seems multiplication occurs from left to right.

Comment: Right, use `m2` so every intermediate multiplication is promoted to `long`. Multiplication is left-associative, so it goes from left to right.

Comment: Multiplication is associative, so the order wouldn't matter.  However it is computed left to right in cases it does matter such as calling methods which return a number.

Comment: Does the concern relate **only** to overflow? The numbers appear to be time related, so left-hand values seem fixed. Or is there a performance element also? Millions of calculations?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use the `m2` line instead of the `m3` line.

Java evaluates the multiplication operator `*` from [left to right](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), so `24 * 60` is evaluated first.

It just so happens that `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` (one `1000`) doesn't overflow, so that by the time you multiply by `1000L` (the second `1000`), the product is promoted to `long` before multiplying, so that overflow doesn't take place.

But as you mentioned in your comments, more factors can cause overflow in the `int` data type before multiplying the last `long` number, yielding an incorrect answer.  It's better to use a `long` literal for the first (left-most) number as in `m2` to avoid overflow from the start.  Alternatively, you can cast the first literal as a `long`, e.g. `(long) 24 * 60 * ...`.

Answer (score 20):

In this case  -

```
long m = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

The right of the assignment is evaluated first. At right there is no `long` type data. All are `int`. So the `JVM` try to fit the result in an `int` then the overflow occurred.

And in the second case -

```
long m2 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
long m3 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000L;
```

Here one operand of the multiplication is `long`. So other are prompted to `long` automatically. The result is trying to fit to a `long`. Finally the assignment is done with `m2` and `m3`.

And yes the associativity of multiplication from left to right - means the left operand is taken first. And Based on this fact I think in this scenario we should use -

```
long m2 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000;
```

this statement, since at this statement the promotion to `long` taken places earlier which reduces the risk of overflow.

Comment: "The left of the assignment is evaluated first."... did you mean the right?

Comment: There's still a typo in the second sentence :)

Comment: @Ruslan, I think I have problem with left-right :(. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[Since expressions are evaluated from left to right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), I would prefer your first solution (`m2 = ...`).

Reasoning: Let's look at a slightly different example.

```
long g = Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2 * 2L;
```

This expression will evaluate to `-4` since only the last multiplication casts the first expression to `long` (which is `-2` at this point in time, because both operands are `int`). If you write

```
long g = Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2L * 2;
```

instead, `g` will hold the expected value of `8589934588` since the first multiplication yields a result of type `long`.

Answer (score 6):

Multiplying works from left to right, and `int * int` produces `int`. So

```
24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000
```

is same as

```
(((24 * 60)* 60) * 1000) * 1000
```

which gives us

```
(((1440)* 60) * 1000) * 1000
((  86400   ) * 1000) * 1000
(    86400000       ) * 1000
```

and finally because of integer overflow (since `86400000000` is too big for integer which max value is `2147483647`) result will be

```
500654080
```

You can eliminate integer overflow by using `long` as one of arguments (`int * long` and `long * int` produces `long`).

In this case you can do it at start like you did in case of `m2`: `24L * 60` which will produce `long` `1440L` which again will be multiplied by int `60` producing new `long`, and so on, producing only `long` values.

`m3` case works here because you are multiplying `86400000` by `1000L` which means that you are avoiding integer overflow since result will be `long`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's multiply more numbers, this line will overflow even there is a `1000L`:

```
long m3 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 *  1000 * 1000L;
```

While this will give correct result:

```
long m3 = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000 *  1000 * 1000;
```

So we are sure that java start multiplying from left to right and we have to start with `Long` from the left to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when we use long as one operand the other all `int` type operand get prompted to `long`.

The expression in java evaluated from left to right.