# Why changing the data type changing the whole result?

Tags: java, multiplication

I wrote a program to calculate the multiplication of odd numbers between `1` and `100`. So why does changing the data type give me a whole different output? Why is the output a negative number when I use `int`? Additionally, the other results seem weird.
Code:

```
long total = 1L;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        total *= i;
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

The output in different cases :

5196472710489536419 (if total is `long`)

-373459037 (if total is `int`)

2.7253921397507295E78 (if total is `double`)

Infinity (if total is `float`)

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121698/java-sum-2-negative-numbers

Comment: Also, you might want to add a `System.out.println(total);` inside the `for` loop to see how the value is changing when the `for` loop is executing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow occurs with multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606365/overflow-occurs-with-multiplication)

Comment: @AlexRudenko yeah it answered a lot but I still don't understand the difference of outputs when using double and long. I think both of them should give the same output

Comment: @QusayAbuAuda The actual result for `total` is `2725392139750729502980713245400918633290796330545803413734328823443106201171875`, but the type `long` has an upper limit of `9223372036854775807`, so the result cannot be stored in a `long` typed variable.

Comment: @QusayAbuAuda The result cannot be saved in a `double` typed variable either, as double has a precision of ~15 digits, but this number have ~78 digits. The value in a `double` type variable will not be precise to hold that value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With different datatypes, the result would [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) in different ways. The result when using a `double` looks correct, although you're probably losing a lot of precision there. If you want to properly multiply an integer of arbitrary size, you should probably use a [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```java
BigInteger total = BigInteger.ONE;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        total = total.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Side note: instead of iterating all the `int`s between `1` and `100` and checking if they are odd or not, you could start with `1` and then increment each iteration by `2` instead of `1`:

```java
BigInteger total = BigInteger.ONE;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i+=2) {
    total = total.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: Why using long is not correct ?

Comment: @QusayAbuAuda The value is too big for the `long` type.

Comment: @QusayAbuAuda Program's reply is correct - the value is too large, and even a `long` will overflow